# How to draw graph like this image?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to draw graph like this image using highchart?.. I already tried with line and some other types i cant able get this design..

[image]

Comment: could you please attach the image?

Comment: already attached image (http://i.stack.imgur.com/nMUR4.png)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nMUR4.png...

Comment: You can use bar or inverted column range in case of your chart. Look here: http://www.highcharts.com/demo

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński This would be the apt link: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange